# Nutch with solr to index PDF by given url

Tags: indexing, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I'm very new to Nutch and Solr, I want Nutch to index the PDF in URL which i inject. I have following this Document.[link](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) Once I tried to run this Query to fetch, Am facing this error.

```
surukam@surukam-Lenovo:~$ cp -r $Desktop/wiki/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/* $Desktop/wiki/solr/server/solr/configsets/nutch/
```

cp: cannot stat '/wiki/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/*': No such file or directory.

I don't know what is this. I have downloaded the solr-7.5.0.tgz No Nutch  folder has been found inside by default.  Can anyone help me with this ., Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [NutchTutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) says
`cp -r ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/server/solr/configsets/_default/* ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/server/solr/configsets/nutch/
`
Did you really install Solr into `/wiki/`? Note that the variable `$Desktop` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for you answer bro, I have installed nutch(1.15 v) and Solr (7.5.0) inside **Desktop/wiki folder.** I am following this document[link](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). In this document all the steps has been executed correctly. but once i run this query `${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/bin/solr create -c nutch -d ${APACHE_SOLR_HOME}/server/solr/configsets/nutch/conf/` I got that error.  My Goal is I. I want to fetch and index the PDF content on given url. I am very new to Nutch and solr, guide me pls, Refer me a good document so that I can start with scratch.

Comment: Removing the $ in front of Desktop should fix the issue.